# Plot odds ratio with confidence interval python

Tags: python, plot, confidence-interval

I am trying to represent odds ratios in python in this way:

```
ax = sns.scatterplot(data=df_result, x="odd_ratio", y="iso")
plt.axvline(1.0, color='black', linestyle='--')
```

[image]

But I would like to have horizontal bars for each odds ratio indicating the confidence interval.
In my dataframe `df_result` I have the information about the lower and upper bound (`df_result['lower_conf]` and `df_result['upper_conf]`). How can I plot the confidence interval? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I share with you my code, its for a vertical plot but you can changue the axis. I have a table with the 5%, the 95% and the OR value in different columns

```
sns.set_style("whitegrid")
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7, 5))
ax.set_yscale("log")
ax.axhline(1, ls='--', linewidth=1, color='black')

n = 0
for index, i in df.iterrows():
    x = [n,n]
    y = [i["5%"], i["95%"]]
    ax.plot(x, y, "_-", markersize = 15, markeredgewidth= 3, linewidth = 3, color=sns.color_palette("muted")[n])

    x = [n]
    y = [i["Odds Ratio"]]
    ax.plot(x, y, "o", color=sns.color_palette("muted")[n], markersize = 10)
    n += 1

ax.set_xlabel("")
ax.set_ylabel("Odds Ratio")
ax.set_xticklabels(["", "Resistant", "Focal Epilepsy", "> 3 seizures/month", "Polytherapy", "DDD > 1", "Adverse effects"], rotation=45)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJwI7.png)